# Autoencoders For Multivariate Time-series Anomaly Detection

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, autoencoders, anomaly-detection, multivariate-regression

I have a multivariate time series of size (1e6, 15) and would like to fit a LSTM autoencoder. I prepare data with multivariate rolling windows (one step rolling) where each sample has (1, 5, 15) dimension. Samples are fed to LSTM network with the input ***X*** of size (-1, 5, 15), the first dimension (-1) is the number of samples, the second dimension is number of time steps in each sample and third dimension is the number of features.

Then I use reconstruction error between output ***X*'** and input ***X*** sample. This method makes no forecast, instead, it reproduces the input signal.

1. what is the best size for the autoencoder output? (1, 5, 15) or (1, 1, 15)?
2. Am I better off building a LSTM forecasting network? This means I will have to predict the next time steps based on previous time steps (needs labels ***y***) and then minimise prediction error instead of reconstruction error?